# Cordova Background GeoLocation Server Update

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, android-intentservice

Usecase: Track associate location, as soon as he logs-in but closes the app later.

Using https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation plugin. 
In debug mode, its showing the values, however, in the callback function, its not making the server calls.
renderMaps function calls navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
        renderMaps();

        var callbackFn = function(location) {
            var data = 'longitude='+ location.longitude + '&latitude=' + location.latitude + '&id=' + vm.user_id + '&token=' + vm.accessToken;
            window.longitude_sel = location.latitude;
            window.latitude_sel = location.longitude;
            console.log("" + data);
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "https://example.com/partner/location",
                 data: data,
                 success: function(response){
                        console.log("RESPONSE" + response);
                      }
                  });
            backgroundGeolocation.finish();
        };

        var failureFn = function(error) {
            console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
        };

        // BackgroundGeolocation is highly configurable. See platform specific configuration options
        backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
            desiredAccuracy: 5,
            stationaryRadius: 0,
            distanceFilter: 30,
            interval: 60000,
            stopOnTerminate: false,
            startOnBoot: false,
            startForeground: true,
            stopOnStillActivity: false,
            debug: true
        });

        backgroundGeolocation.start();
        console.log("TEST");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. Its working in my case:

```
    $$(document).on('deviceready', function() {



   cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
   alert('device working!');
   var userId=localStorage.getItem("userId");
   if(userId!=null)
   {
         BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
            locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
            desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
            stationaryRadius: 50,
            distanceFilter: 50,
            notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
            notificationText: 'enabled',
            debug: true,
            interval: 10000,
            fastestInterval: 5000,
            activitiesInterval: 10000,
            url: 'http://example.com/index.php/locations/savebackgroundlocation',
            httpHeaders: {
              "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('stack' + ":" + 'pwd@123#')
            },
            // customize post properties
            postTemplate: {
              lat: '@latitude',
              lon: '@longitude'

            }
      });

      BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function(status) {
          BackgroundGeolocation.start(); //triggers start on start event
      });



   }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using *'url'* option of the plugin.
don't expect your callback to work every time, as your app activity might be killed in the background by the OS, which will also kill your callback.

besides this, service should survive the kill, so if you use *url* option of the plugin, you can still get your updates on the server

Answer (score 0):

I had to give ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission

In the file plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/plugin.xml you need to add:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

See more here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/background